# Issue in starting OPenstack Nova while installing using devstack

Tags: python, openstack, lxc, openstack-nova, devstack

I got below issue when nova tried to start.

```
/usr/local/bin/nova-compute --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
cloud@CloudServer:/opt/stack/devstack$ /usr/local/bin/nova-compute --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf

2015-02-10 07:26:42.226 DEBUG nova.servicegroup.api [-] ServiceGroup driver defined as an instance of db from (pid=3411) __new__ /opt/stack/nova/nova/servicegroup/api.py:65
2015-02-10 07:26:53.201 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2015-02-10 07:26:58.820 INFO nova.virt.driver [-] Loading compute driver 'ncflex.nova.virt.flex.LXCDriver'
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 ERROR nova.virt.driver [-] Unable to load the virtualization driver
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/driver.py", line 1402, in load_compute_driver
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver     virtapi)
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 52, in import_object_ns
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver     return import_class(import_str)(*args, **kwargs)
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ncflex/nova/virt/flex/driver.py", line 46, in __init__
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver     self.containers = containers.Containers(virtapi)
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ncflex/nova/virt/flex/containers.py", line 73, in __init__
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver     vif_class = importutils.import_class(CONF.lxc.vif_driver)
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 27, in import_class
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver     __import__(mod_str)
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/local
/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ncflex/nova/virt/flex/vifs.py", line 23, in <module>
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver     from nova import processutils
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver ImportError: cannot import name processutils
2015-02-10 07:27:02.860 TRACE nova.virt.driver 
cloud@CloudServer:/opt/stack/devstack$

ImportError: cannot import name processutils.
```

Any idea why this happens, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `nova-compute-flex` driver, which is neither (a) an official OpenStack project or (b) included by default in `devstack`.

Looking at the error:

```
TRACE nova.virt.driver     from nova import processutils
TRACE nova.virt.driver ImportError: cannot import name processutils
```

It seems like a bug in the flex driver.  If you look, e.g., in `ncflex/nova/virt/flex/volumes.py` you see:

```
from nova.openstack.common import processutils
```

And that works just fine.  It's possible that modifying `vifs.py` to replace:

```
from nova import processutils
```

With:

```
from nova.openstack.common import processutils
```

Would fix that error, although since this seem like something that would be fairly easy to spot I expect you will find other problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file ../stack/nova/openstack-common.conf has an entry
module=processutils
Several days ago entry
module=log
was removed from openstack-common.conf
and in meantime I am getting :-
[n-cpu screen log with error for import - from nova.openstack.common import log](http://textuploader.com/j1xu) 
In meantime I don't see entry you need in openstack-common.conf.
Please, respond does larsks suggestion work for you.